# Changing response serializer for a particular call inside AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2

I am subclassing `AFHTTPSessionManager` to make different `POST` requests to one server. All responses from the server are returned in JSON format, so I set response serializer for `AFHTTPSessionManager` to `AFJSONResponseSerializer`. But for one `POST` request I need to change response serializer to some other (leaving all other to use `AFJSONResponseSerializer`). Is is possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try AFCompoundResponseSerializer, you may add different serializers in it.

Comment: Answer doesn't seem very clear. Too short to be very useful, I'm afraid.